# Terraform how to send message to SQS configured with cloudwatch

Tags: terraform, amazon-sqs

I have a terraform project. I need to configure it so that when a message ends up on an SQS queue, then another message is sent to a different queue. So far I have this.

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "x" {
  name                       = "x"
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 600
  message_retention_seconds  = 1209600
  redrive_policy             = "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"${aws_sqs_queue.x_deadletter.arn}\",\"maxReceiveCount\":3}"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "x_deadletter" {
  name                      = "x_dlq"
  message_retention_seconds = 1209600
}
```

I have looked in terraform docs and googled and I dont see how to do this. I think I have to do this with cloudwatch but it is unclear. Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to use a dead-letter-queue for messages that can't be processed to go to another queue or _all_ messages to be cloned to the second queue?

Comment: I want to send a message to a an sqs queue when something ends up in a dead letter queue. It's for alerting that something ended up in the dead letter queue.

Comment: So it's not sending a message from one queue to another queue in the case of failure or for whatever reason. I want to actually just create a new message and send it to a queue B when something ends up in a queue A. But i want this to be entirely managed by terraform.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show this debugging? It isn't clear that this is actually a Terraform related issue. It would be nice to see the steps taken, show the flow of the message and the problem (when it should hit the DLQ but doesn't). I'm unclear on what a failed message is in this context to go into the DLQ.